# aggregation and ascending merge of table columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

how can i do this ?
The Unique combination of columns is Number + Element, Cond1..n are SUMming() and Variable1..n need to be equal too.

Here is what i think about

[image]

Have you any idea how i can attain this ? In real DB it has few thousand rows.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a7d0/1

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Take a look at pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [String Aggregation in the World of SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691102/String-Aggregation-in-the-World-of-SQL-Server) to get the better understanding of how the `Group_concat` works in the sql server. Try this,

```
SELECT
     t.Number
     ,[KEY]= STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + tt.[key]
          FROM SourceTb tt
          WHERE t.Number = tt.Number and t.Element = tt.Element and t.Variable1 = tt.Variable1
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    ,t.Element
    ,t.Variable1
    ,SUM(CAST(t.cond1 as INT))
    ,SUM(CAST(t.cond2 as INT))
FROM SourceTb t
GROUP BY t.Number
    ,t.Element
    ,t.Variable1
ORDER BY t.Number desc
```

[HERE is working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a7d0/25)

Comment: Wow thank you this works ! :-) I will play little bit with that STUFF function which i didnt know about :-)